# Yet another proposed change is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

I got an inbox notification:

> proposed change                                      xxxx ago
>   [html: "Input Control Elements" change needs review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/99424?draftId=84216)
>   The Great Example Merge

Note that this edit appears to be:

- in the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag
- Created by [RamenChef **1,663**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6392939)
- ID: 99424
- The [no-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/99424?noredirect=1) version still redirects, unlike [another](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/99454?noredirect=1) unrelated one.

Upon clicking the link, I get an error.

Comment: I may be getting a related error: [Documentation Review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes), gets a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` on `http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/review/changes/next` (as seen in console). Text message is "An error occurred when loading the first review item". Try again fails to correct error.

Comment: Looking into this.